# Finding min distance between elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, time-complexity

I'm trying to find the minimum distance between 2 given elements of an array.
for example, in the following array {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} the distance between elements 3,7 is 4.
I've written a code that successfully calculates that distance, but if there are duplicates, it doesn't work.
Below is what I've written so far. What am I missing? should I add any conditions?
Also, it should be done at a complexity no greater than O(n).

```java
public static int findMinDiff(int [] a, int x, int y) {
             
    //previous index and min distance
    int next = 0,curr = 0, min_dist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
         
    for(int i=0 ; i<a.length ; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==x)
        {
            curr = i; 
        }
        else if(a[i] == y){
            next = i;
        }
            
    }
    
    min_dist = Math.abs(curr - next);
    if(min_dist==Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        return -1;
     
    return min_dist;
}
```

Comment: if given array is sorted for sure, you can try binary search for better complexity. And for the duplicates  you can check for most right or most left. [This might help](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/)

Comment: what should i add to the code to check most left/right? and btw the array is not necessarily sorted

Comment: If it is sorted array like `1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6` and you get  input as `3` and `6`, You need to find most right 3 and most left 6 because you know 6 is bigger than 3 so it has to be on right. To find most right, just go 1 by 1 or do binary search until you dont get 3. If the array is not sorted, this maybe not works.

Comment: If array is not sorted and  you need min distance(you did not say what kind of distance you need) you can check 1 by 1 as i said before and for each `3` you find the nearest `6` distance. After eaching each `3` save the sortest  distance and return it.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int findMinDiff(int [] a, int x, int y) {
    //previous index and min distance
    int next = -1,curr = -1, min_dist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for(int i=0 ; i<a.length ; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==x)
        {
            curr = i;
            if(next != -1) {
                min_dist = Math.min(min_dist, Math.abs(curr-next));
            }
        }
        else if(a[i] == y){
            next = i;
            if(curr != -1){
                min_dist = Math.min(min_dist, Math.abs(curr-next));
            }
        }

    }

    if(min_dist==Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        return -1;

    return min_dist;
}
```

This might help.

Comment: Doesn't work for {1,2,3,3,5,6,7}

Comment: @Sigma9 The minimum distance between  3 and 7 in the given input is 3 I believe I had ran this code and it gave the right output. Please let me know whether you were mentioning as 3 and 7 as the input or not.

The idea of the code was to calculate minimum whenever the pair of input was found.

Comment: Nah man, it was my mistake, apologies. your code works great. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If there are duplicate values in the array your algorithm does not work because it always remembers only the right-most x and y values that it encounters in the array and only calculates the distance between them in the end.

Even if the array is not sorted, you can still meet the O(n) requirement, by tracking 3 variables as you traverse the array:

1. the last encountered x index,
2. the last encountered y index
3. the shortest distance so far

Every time you encounter either an x value or and y value, update all 3 variables that you are tracking. Which means that you would calculate the distance of the newly found pair and compare it to the current shortest distance. If it is shorter, save it, otherwise ignore it.

Since the distance calculation and updating the values takes constant time, you still end with a O(n) time complexity when the end of the array is reached and the shortest distance variable will contain the shortest distance.

The key place in you algorithm would be here

```
        if(a[i]==x)
        {
            curr = i;
            // here if you found a complete pair, calculate the
            // distance and, if it is less than the current shortest
            // distance, update the shortest distance variable
        }
        else if(a[i] == y){
            next = i;
            // here if you found a complete pair, calculate the
            // distance and, if it is less than the current shortest
            // distance, update the shortest distance variable
        }
```

Also remove the old distance calculation `min_dist = Math.abs(curr - next);`

Comment: I see your logic, I'm having a hard time implementing what you've written..

Comment: @Sigma9 No worries, since Mahadev posted a completely working solution in code. And, yes, it works correctly for `{1,2,3,3,5,6,7}` as well, unless you specified the requirements in a wrong way in your question. Here is another test input for you to try `{1,2,3,4,7,1,7,3,1,7}`.

Comment: You are correct. I had a mistake in my tester. i appreciate your help!